# Representation of Cross Product: A tikz Approach

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

How can I produce the following graph in tikz:

[image]

Comment: It is basically produced with segment lines that can be drawn with `\draw (x,y) -- (z,w);` where `x,y,z,w` are the coordinates with the points. Also options should be used to change the line style, for example `\draw[dashed]`

Comment: It is just the floating ranges that I don't see how to make.

Comment: General solution would be nice if it was explained.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That’s quite easy, I’ll show a way using different “varaibles”. This make the code a little more complex but also more flexible.

**Step 1**
Set up the basic environment: load the package and the `arrows` and `calc` library:

```
\documentclass{article}% ... or whatever you like

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   % picture commands
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Every thing that follows goes inside the `{tikzpicture}`.

**Step 2**
Set up the variables. We’ll set up the vectors as coordinates, starting from the origin.

```
\coordinate (A) at (3,0);
\coordinate (B) at (0,-2);
```

and the upper left edge of the cross product

```
\coordinate (cross prod) at (1,4);
```

We add a simply `\def` to store the length of the ticks

```
\def\tick{0.1}
```

**Step 3**
Draw the axes: Use  the `\draw` command with the option `->` to add the arrow tips. We us a `node` with some options at the end of the path to add the labels.

```
\draw [->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node [below] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node [left]  {$y$};
```

Then we use a `\foreach` loop to add the ticks.

```
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
   \draw (\x,\tick/2) -- ++(0,-\tick) node [below] {\x};
\foreach \y in {1,...,4}
   \draw (\tick/2,\y) -- ++(-\tick,0) node [left] {\y};
```

**Step 4**
Draw the vectors. We define a style to make all vectors look the same and add it as option to `{tikzpicture}`. The vectors should be `thick`, and have “arrow” tips on both sides (`[-)`)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   vec/.style={thick,[-)},
]
```

Now we can draw the vectors. Starting at a certian point and then using the `++` syntax to add the components of the vector. Again we use a node to add the names.

```
\draw [vec] (1,-1) -- ++(A) node [midway,below] {$A$};
\draw [vec] (-1,4) -- ++(B) node [midway,left]  {$B$};
```

**Step 5**

Now draw the cross product. First we draw the filling in `gray` using the `\fill` macro and the `rectangle` path operation.

```
\fill [gray] (cross prod) rectangle ++($(A)+(B)$);
```

An then the borders and the label using `\draw` again. The `-|` path operation allows the automatic creation of the right angle.

```
\draw [thick] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) -| ($(cross prod)+(B)$);
\draw [thick,dashed] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) |- ($(cross prod)+(B)$)
   node [pos=0.25,right] {$A \times B$};
```

And that’s it.

[image: cross product]

**full code**

```
\documentclass{article}% ... or whatever you like

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    vec/.style={thick,[-)},
]
    % Step 2
    \coordinate (A) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,-2);
    \coordinate (cross prod) at (1,4);
    \def\tick{0.2}
    % Step 3
    \draw [->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node [left]  {$y$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
        \draw (\x,\tick/2) -- ++(0,-\tick) node [below] {\x};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        \draw (\tick/2,\y) -- ++(-\tick,0) node [left] {\y};
    % Step 4
    \draw [vec] (1,-1) -- ++(A) node [midway,below] {$A$};
    \draw [vec] (-1,4) -- ++(B) node [midway,left]  {$B$};
    % Step 5
    \fill [gray] (cross prod) rectangle ++($(A)+(B)$);
    \draw [thick] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) -| ($(cross prod)+(B)$);
    \draw [thick,dashed] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) |- ($(cross prod)+(B)$)
        node [pos=0.25,right] {$A \times B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### update

with some adjustments this will work with every two vectors.

[image: cross product II]

```
\documentclass{article}% ... or whatever you like

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    vec/.style={thick,[-)},
]
    % Step 2
    \coordinate (A) at (3,-1);
    \coordinate (B) at (-0.5,-2);
    \coordinate (cross prod) at (1,4);
    \def\tick{0.2}
    % Step 3
    \draw [->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw [->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node [left]  {$y$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,5}
        \draw (\x,\tick/2) -- ++(0,-\tick) node [below] {\x};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        \draw (\tick/2,\y) -- ++(-\tick,0) node [left] {\y};
    % Step 4
    \draw [vec] (1,-1) -- ++(A) node [midway,below] {$A$};
    \draw [vec] (-1,4) -- ++(B) node [midway,left]  {$B$};
    % Step 5
    \fill [gray] (cross prod) -- +(A) -- +($(A)+(B)$) -- +(B);
    \draw [thick] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) -- (cross prod) -- ($(cross prod)+(B)$);
    \draw [thick,dashed] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) -- ($(cross prod)+(A)+(B)$)
        node [midway,right] {$A \times B$} -- ($(cross prod)+(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this one uses the `+` syntax which means that the coordinate is realtive but without setting it as new reference point, as the `++` does.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using this many times, you may like to create a macro. This is to illustrate how to convert Tobi's excellent code into one.

```
\documentclass{article}% ... or whatever you like

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}

\newcommand\crossprod[4][5]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    vec/.style={thick,[-)},
]
    % Step 2
    \coordinate (A) at #3;
    \coordinate (B) at #4;
    \coordinate (cross prod) at #2;
    \def\tick{0.2}
    % Step 3
    \draw [-stealth] (-1,0) -- ($(#1,0)+(0.5,0)$) node [below] {$x$};
    \draw [-stealth] (0,-1) -- ($(0,#1)+(0,0.5)$) node [left]  {$y$};
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
        \draw (\x,\tick/2) -- ++(0,-\tick) node [below] {\x};
    \foreach \y in {1,...,#1}
        \draw (\tick/2,\y) -- ++(-\tick,0) node [left] {\y};
    % Step 4
    \draw [vec] (1,-1) -- ++(A) node [midway,below] {$A$};
    \draw [vec] (-1,4) -- ++(B) node [midway,left]  {$B$};
    % Step 5
    \fill [gray!30] (cross prod) -- +(A) -- +($(A)+(B)$) -- +(B);
    \draw [thick] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) -- (cross prod) -- ($(cross prod)+(B)$);
    \draw [thick,dashed] ($(cross prod)+(A)$) -- ($(cross prod)+(A)+(B)$)
        node [midway,right] {$A \times B$} -- ($(cross prod)+(B)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% #1 -- Optional argument for length of x and y axes; default is 5. Adjust for suitability
%% #2 -- upper left edge of the cross product. Adjust for suitability
%% #3 -- vector A as coordinate, starting from the origin.
%% #4 -- vector B as coordinate, starting from the origin.

\begin{document}
\crossprod{(1,5)}{(3,0)}{(0,-2)}

\crossprod[6]{(2,5)}{(3,-2)}{(-0.5,-2)}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font={\small}]
\draw[-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex] (0,-0.5) -- (0,5.5) node[left] {$y$};
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
{
\draw (0.1,\x) -- (-0.1,\x) node[left] {$\x$};
\draw (\x,0.1) -- (\x,-0.1) node[below] {$\x$};
}
\path[fill=lightgray] (1,2) rectangle +(3,2);
\draw[thick] (1,2) -- (1,4) -- (4,4);
\draw[thick,dashed] (1,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,4) node[right,midway] {$A\times B$};
\draw[very thick] (1,-1) node {\small [} -- (4,-1) node {)} node[below,midway] {$A$};
\draw[very thick] (-1,2) node[rotate=90] {[} -- (-1,4) node[rotate=90] {)}
node[left,midway] {$B$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```